# read stdin as if it comes from a file using Bash?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Suppose I have a script:

```
foo.sh
```

Which expects to open two files:

```
./foo.sh biz baz
```

---

I have, in this case, pre-calculated the file and would like to pass to `foo.sh` from the pipeline *as if it were a file* (like I would do with a c executable):

```
# in pseudo code
./bar.sh initial_baz | ./foo.sh biz -
```

---

Solutions I have tried:

```
./bar.sh initial_baz ...
| ./foo.sh biz -
| ./foo.sh biz /dev/stdin
| ./foo.sh biz </dev/stdin
| ./foo.sh biz <$(/dev/stdin)
| ./foo.sh biz $(/dev/stdin)
./foo.sh biz $(./bar.sh initial_baz)
./foo.sh biz <$(./bar.sh initial_baz)
./foo.sh biz `./bar.sh initial_baz`

etc.
```

There must be a way to redirect as if stdin were a file...?

Comment: pass baz through a fifo , or in other words, named pipe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should have worked:

```
./bar.sh initial_baz | ./foo.sh biz /dev/stdin
```

You can also use [process substitution](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html).

```
./foo.sh biz <(./bar.sh initial_baz)
```

There are some cases where a pipe won't work, though (process substitution uses pipes internally): If `foo.sh` tries to open the file multiple times, or needs to seek in the file. A pipe is a FIFO queue, you can't seek or read it multiple times.

Comment: If that works, then `./bar.sh initial_baz | ./foo.sh biz /dev/stdin` should have worked as well

Comment: @thatotherguy ok great.  Yeah, I uncovered an error once we locked down what should work.

Comment: @thatotherguy So, with respect to `/dev/stdin` this does not work; however, the redirection does work (I have side by side test cases--one works, the other doesn't).  If I have time, I'll try to get to the bottom of it.